# Best way to handle multiple APIs with the same output type in single one in ASP.NET Core using GetRequiredService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, api-design

I have several Get APIs that return the same type of output, and I  am attempting to create a single method to support all APIs requests instead of multiple APIs . To do so, user sets the name of class as string in `inputDto`  and using `GetType` and then `GetRequiredService` the target class is found and its process method is called. Everything is fine and there is no problem, but I'm concerned about what is happening behind the scene, because `GetRequiredService` is an inadvisable method, unless in inevitable condition, due to lack of ability to fully manage created instances, caching or torn lifestyle problems. To resolve disposing issue, I make use of `using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope()){}`.

My question is whether revised method that I have written at the end of question, is safe, harmless and avoids issues like disposing, caching and torn lifestyle or any other unseen issues.

```
      public async virtual Task<List<CustomDto>> GetBaseInformationList(InputDto input)
        {
            string className = input.TargetStategy;
            Type classType = Type.GetType(className);
            var strategyClass =(IStrategy)_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(classType);
            var result = await strategyClass.Process<List<CustomDto>>(input);
            
            return result;
        }
```

```
    public class GetBaseInformation1 : Strategy, ITransientDependency, IStrategy
    {
        public override async Task<List<T>> Process<T>(InputDto data)
        {
       var result= ...get data process...
            return result;

        }

    }
```

```
    public class GetBaseInformation2 :  Strategy, ITransientDependency, IStrategy
    {
        public override async Task<List<T>> Process<T>(InputDto data)
        {
            var result=... get data process...
            return result;

        }

    }
```

```
  public abstract class Strategy
    {
        public abstract Task<List<T>> Process<T>(InputDto data);
    }
```

```
   public interface IStrategy
    {
        Task<List<T>> Process<T>(InputDto data);
    }
```

**Here's the Revised `GetBaseInformationList` method after putting the code in `using(){}`:**

```
      public async virtual Task<List<CustomDto>> GetBaseInformationList(InputDto input)
        {
          using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                string className = input.TargetStategy;
                Type classType = Type.GetType(className);
                var strategyClass = (IStrategy)_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(classType);
                var result = await strategyClass.Process<List<CustomDto>>(input);

                return result;
            }
        }
```

Comment: `_serviceProvider.CreateScope()` is not for resolving some dispose issues, it is designed to specify custom lifetime of you service. At second, to make use of scoped services you should replace `_serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(...)` to `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(...)`. And use of reflection `Type.GetType(className)` is considered to be bad practice due to performance overhead - i would rethink approach. What if to use different `InputDto` types?

Comment: Is it possible to use simple switch statement here? Would be better than using of reflection.

Comment: Dear @Ryan, thank you for your responses. Yes, you are right, and I missed using the scope in the using statement. Regarding the switch statement, there are many target classes, and using switch would require updating the method every time. It's a tradeoff between using GetType or switch, though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, was struck with one use case for typical usage of Factory method:

```
abstract class InputDto
{
    public abstract Strategy CreateStrategy();
    
    //other members omitted for brevity
}
```

For every type of service you just create InputDto-derived type, and implement its CreateStrategy there. Voila!
This is typical usage of factory method, described in GoF.
There are a hierachy of types, and every type should be processed by only specific service for that type, which one - this type only knows about it.
And you can also add one more factory method in InputDto for creating specific derivatives from it, but these are implementation details.

**UPDATE**
To use reflection or make a lot of (or not?) new types, this is a question.
Anyway, there is branching here, you can't get rid of it.
It's up to you to decide.
Cheers!

Comment: With having the `CreateStrategy` factory method on the DTO, how would you handle the scenario where the strategy implementations require dependencies of their own that would come from the DI Container?

Comment: `CreateStrategy` implementations would use `IServiceCollection` (as inner state) of DTO. Yep, looks not so good for just simple DTOs. Offer better solution then. From other hand, DTOs are just containers of data, they should not have any logic, that's why we delegate creation to DI-container. Agree?

Answer (score 0):

i have written a sample project for you.
please take a look at [here][1]

let me now if this is helpfull
[1]: https://github.com/roozbeh-hoseiny/MultipleApiWithSameResponseSample